# Error with CollectionView RemainingItemsThreshholdReached Command

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, prism, collectionview

I use Prism MVVM in my app. So here is my XAML code

```
 IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                 Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">

        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
                        RemainingItemsThreshold="1"
                        RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding UpdateImagesCommand}">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                             Span="3"/>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="2">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ff:CachedImage 
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    Aspect="AspectFill"
                    Source="{Binding Source, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <ff:CachedImage.Transformations>
                            <ffTransformations:CropTransformation />
                        </ff:CachedImage.Transformations>
                </ff:CachedImage>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
    </RefreshView>
```

As you can see here I have parameter RemainingItemsThreshold with the value "1", and binding anUpdateImagesCommand to the RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand

Here is a part of a code in view model of this xaml page

```
private ObservableCollection _images;
public ObservableCollection Images
{
get { return _images; }
set { SetProperty(ref _images, value); }
}
private DelegateCommand _refreshCommand;
public DelegateCommand RefreshCommand =>
_refreshCommand ?? (_refreshCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteRefreshCommand));
 private DelegateCommand _updateImagesCommand;
    public DelegateCommand UpdateImagesCommand =>
        _updateImagesCommand ?? (_updateImagesCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteUpdateImagesCommand));
void ExecuteUpdateImagesCommand()
{
//Image im = new Image();
//im.Source = "Huayra3.jpg";
//Image im7 = new Image();
//im7.Source = "Huayra1.jpg";
 //Images.Add(im7);
        //Images.Add(im7);
        //Images.Add(im);
        //Images.Add(im);
        //Images.Add(im);
        //Images.Add(im);
    }
void ExecuteRefreshCommand()
{
// refresh posts feed command
IsRefreshing = false;
}

public AccountPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IUserDataService userDataService) :
base(navigationService)
{
_userDataService = userDataService;
CurrentUser = userDataService.CurrentUser;
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CurrentUser.ImagePath))
        {
            this.CurrentUser.ImagePath = "user_avatar.jpg";     
        }

        Images = new ObservableCollection<Image>();

        Image im = new Image();
        im.Source = "Huayra3.jpg";
        Images.Add(im);
        Image im1 = new Image();
        im1.Source = "Huayra1.jpg";
        Images.Add(im1);
        Image im2 = new Image();
        im2.Source = "Huayra4.jpg";
        Images.Add(im2);
        Image im3 = new Image();
        im3.Source = "Huayra3.jpg";
        Images.Add(im3);
        Image im4 = new Image();
        im4.Source = "Huayra1.jpg";
        Images.Add(im4);
        Image im5 = new Image();
        im5.Source = "Huayra4.jpg";
        Images.Add(im5);
        Image im6 = new Image();
        im6.Source = "Huayra3.jpg";
        Images.Add(im6);
        Image im7 = new Image();
        im7.Source = "Huayra1.jpg";
        Images.Add(im7);
        Images.Add(im7);

        Images.Add(im7);
        Images.Add(im7);
        Images.Add(im7);
        Images.Add(im7);
        Images.Add(im7);
        Images.Add(im);


        //Images.Add(im);
        //Images.Add(im);

    }
```

As you can see I in my VIewModel constructor I've written some values and add it to list. I read microsoft documentation about CollectionView and I know that the UpdateImagesCommand will execute only when the RemainingItemsThreshold is reached. But ExecuteUpdateImagesCommand() invokes when I navigate to this page, when I navigating between my pages in my tabbed page randomly. This should not be, but I do not know the reason why this happens. Can smbd help me please?

Comment: According to Microsoft [CollectionView Load data incrementally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data), we can see that the default value of the RemainingItemsThreshold property is -1, for values greater than 0, the RemainingItemsThresholdReached event will be fired when the ItemsSource contains that number of items not yet scrolled to. So do you add update images source when you navigate using ExecuteUpdateImagesCommand?

Comment: I've found another way to fix this problem. I can use the IsActive PRISM property to undertand that this page is that I need.

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your issue by yourself, please remember to post one reply about your solution and mark your reply as answer, it is beneficial to other community members who face the same issue, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've found another way to fix this problem. I can use the IsActive PRISM property to undertand that this page is that I need.

Comment: Can you explain your implementation with a code example?